# Is it possible to choose an Azure ServiceConfiguration during localhost development? Eg. Cloud?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure

On my localhost machine, I'm doing some normal Azure development of some Worker roles.

When ever I debug my role, it uses the `Local` ServiceConfiguration.

Is it possible to say `Please use the Cloud Configuration, even though I know this is my localhost` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Right click on the Cloud Service Project.
2. Select "Properties"
3. Go to "Development" tab
4. Chose your Service Configuration

You shall see this window when selecting the Properties on the Cloud Service Project:
[image: Cloud Service Properties]

By the way, you know you can maintain more than just these two service configurations - as many as you wish.

Comment: Oh wow - so simple. I think this best sums up current emotion: http://upboat.me/hgrf/thank-you-thank-you-thank-you/thank-you-thank-you-thank-you.jpg